Getting error for streamlit -" 'streamlit' is not recognized" and how it can be resolved
I am getting an error for streamlit when running the command "streamlit run model.py"
streamlit is already installed.
This is the error shown.
PS C:\Users\Project\ML\RAG> streamlit run .\model.py
streamlit : The term 'streamlit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ streamlit run .\model.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


The above error can be resolved using the command "python -m streamlit run .\model.py"
PS C:\Users\Project\ML\RAG> python -m streamlit run .\model.py

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://10.110.136.233:8501


